# Compiling on Linux Mint 11

Tags: linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to compile a package on Linux Mint 11, which is based upon Ubuntu 11.04, but am getting the following errors which looks as if they're related to detecting the OS version number.

```
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/rosmake", line 65, in <module>
    if rma.main():   
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/rosmake.py", line 858, in main
    (self.rosdep_check_result, warning) = self.check_rosdep(buildable_packages)  
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/rosmake.py", line 287, in check_rosdep
    r = rosdep.core.Rosdep(packages, robust=True)   
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py", line 296, in __init__
    self.osi = roslib.os_detect.OSDetect(os_list)
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/os_detect.py", line 479, in __init__
    self.detect_os()
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/os_detect.py", line 498, in detect_os
    self._os_version = os_class.get_version()
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/debian.py", line 124, in get_version
    return self.version_map[self.mint_detector.get_version()] KeyError: '11'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?  The binary installation for Ubuntu 11.04 (natty) seems to have worked ok.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10142/compiling-on-linux-mint-11/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-06-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like a bug. You should probably file a [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket).(may require login, let me know if you'd like me to file it on your behalf)

The mint specialization apparently has not been updated since Ubuntu 10.04.

It should work if you edit:

```
/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/debian.py
```

near line 118 there's a list that looks like this:

```
self.version_map = {'9':'10.04',
                    '8':'9.10',
                    '7':'9.04',
                    '6':'8.10',
                    '5':'8.04'}
```

add "'11':'11.04'," to that list and it should work. (and '10':'10.10' for that matter)

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-06-02**:
https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4992

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-06-02**:
I don't wish to, but I will since it probably won't get fixed otherwise.

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-06-02**:
That seems to have resolved the problem.  You can file it as a bug if you wish.